# KeyDown Event Does Not Work When A Slider Is Focused (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, slider, focus, keydown

I am trying to make the focus change away from a slider when the up arrow on the keyboard is pressed. The problem is that the up arrow just increases the value of the slider instead of performing the KeyDown event. Please help, and here is my code if needed:

```
private void slider1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Key == VirtualKey.Up))
        {
            customvolumebutton.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
            label1.Text = "focus changed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you debug? Is the if entered?

Comment: how do i check that? I know KeyDown worked for all the other buttons, but with the slider the value of the slider just increases when the up arrow is pressed

Comment: Debug your keydown method?

Comment: if i debug there are no errors, even where the KeyDown even should be triggered. I tried putting the part that changes the label outside of the if statement and still nothing happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys control the `Value` of the `Slider`. If you want your own behavioir, you can manually handle the routed event by calling `AddHandler` in your page's constructor

```
slider1.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(slider1_KeyDown), true);
```

So just remove your current `KeyDown` subscription as it's no longer needed. And what's inside your `slider1_KeyDown` should now be invoked by any key press.